# Caption position : above of the figure

Tags: captions

I have a problem about positioning of the caption. My code of the figure is like this:

```
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\captionbox{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.}{

   \fbox{\includegraphics[width=4in]{basicLDPC}}}
   \label{fig:dummy}

\end{figure}
```

The output is :

[image: The simple output]

The problem is the caption must be at above of the figure. How can I do that?

Edited

Is there any possible way to add a text after the figure like a footnote to write the source of it?

Thanks

Comment: Where does that `\captionbox` come from?  And please do not post code snippets.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the option `figureposition=top`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove that option
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
    ,format=hang
    ,justification=raggedright
    ,singlelinecheck=false
    ,figureposition=top
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \captionbox{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.\label{fig:dummy}}{%       
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=4in]{basicLDPC}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Off-topic: Please note the % in the 4th last line which was missing.

Comment: Nice answer, but for the \label to work I think it needs to be inside captionbox.

Comment: @Davi thanks for the pointer